# How to map many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework CTP5?

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm trying to map 2 types (user -> languages) using 3 tables (user - junction table - languages), and looks like the modelBuilder is expecting both types to have a reference to each other (like user.languagesSpoken, and language.UsersSpeaking). So basically I can build something like 
`modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x=>x.LanguagesSpoken).WithMany(x=>x.UsersSpeaking)`. 
I don't need a reference from language to user, however - and can't figure out how to map that.. 
Also, is there a way to specify a junction table name ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Language> LanguagesSpoken { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}        

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.LanguagesSpoken)
                    .WithMany()
                    .Map(c => 
                    { 
                        c.ToTable("yourDesiredName"); 
                    });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering what is wrong if define a member to Language as ICollection<User>
Users without fluent. I think that will have same effect. (I do not care how Sql Server manage data, POCO support code without this knowledge.)

Comment: Yes, in that case you don't need the fluent API. It will be automatically configured as a *:* association based on conventions.