# EF Code First: duplicating data on save (many-to-many)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm playing with Entity Framework and hit a stumbling block regarding many-to-many mappings.
Lets say I have two entities, Orders and Products.

Inside my Order entity I have:

```
int OrderID,
double OrderPrice
datetime OrderDate
ICollection<Product> Products
datetime DispactDate
```

and so on...

then inside my product class I have

```
int ProductID
string ProductName
string ProductDescription
```

and so on.

In my Code First EF DB I have a Order Table which maps nicely to my order, a products table with a list of products that can be ordered and then using EF Code-first migrations EF created OrderProducts with foreign keys to both primary keys of the other tables. All good.

However, when I go to save an order which has multiple products in its Product Collection, EF is duplicating all the entries in the Product table. So If I add products 10, 12 & 13, its crating three new rows with three new ID's and mapping to them, rather than the originals. If I then process another order with another 20 existing products, 20 new entries are made in the products table!

In my DBContext I have overridden the onModelCreatingEvent:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasMany(x=>x.Products)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(be =>
                    {
                        be.ToTable("OrderProducts");
                });
```

I'm guessing something is configured wrong here. I got this from [How to map many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework CTP5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188958/how-to-map-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-ctp5)

Previously I had two separate repositories - one for orders and one for products. I've now merged these into orderRepository which exposes both Orders and Products so that I can attach a product to the orderRepository context.
To generate the products, I have a Controller action AddProducts:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult Products(FormCollection selectedProducts)
        {
                currentOrder.Products = new List<Product>();
                foreach (string thisProduct in selectedProducts)
                {
                    int thisProductID = int.Parse(thisProduct);
                    Product selectedProduct = orderRepository.Products.Where(e => e.ProductID == thisProductID).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (selectedProduct != null)
                    {
                        orderRepository.AttachToContext(selectedProduct);
                        currentOrder.Products.Add(selectedProduct);
                    }                    
                }

                orderRepository.saveChanges(currentOrder);
```

}

Comment: can you post the code where you are finding and adding the products to the order?

Comment: Added an example of what I'm doing Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you knock up a little unit test that just creates the context, retrieves a product, creates an order and adds the retrieved product to the order?

That should work absolutely fine. It sounds like you are creating a new product object rather than using a pre-existing one. Or creating one and not setting the appropriate entity key.

It doesn't sound like you are getting it from a different context as you would usually get a warning that it is already attached to another context.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that in `orderRepository` you have a different context instance than in `ProductsRepo`. You should first [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) the products to the `Products` in `orderRepository`'s context.

This is, by the way, an example of why repositories per entity can really get in your way. It is often better to think in aggregate roots if you want to use the repository pattern.

Comment: Yeah this is my suspicion too

Comment: Doesn't seem to have helped. The line before currentOrder.Products.Add(selectedProduct); I've added ProductsRepo.AttachToContext(selectedProduct), which simply does context.Products.Attach(product); but the values are still duplicating.

Comment: You must attach to the context in the orders repository.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Managed to solve this. In my `OrderRepository` I had to manually mark each `Product` with an `EntitySate.Unchanged` status. So, on `SaveOrder()` I now do:

```
foreach (Product product in Orders.Products)
{
  context.Entry(product).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

This is working fine, but I'm curious as to why I had to do this step when each Product inside the order had a valid (and existing) productid already assigned to it?
Strange.